# Is there is a way to identify the text in touch area?

Tags: flutter

I want to identify the text underneath the touch area, Is it possible to do so? below i'll provide a sample

```
Text("This Is the Question 1")
```

I want to identify if user tap on the word `Question`, not the whole text

Note: RichText isn't going to work for my requirement I can't separate the sentence into words

Comment: You'll have to use `RichText` which comes with gesture recognizer.

Comment: Rich text we have to seperate the word right ? For my requirement I can't seperate the word, Actually I am getting an array of sentences

Comment: Yes, you'll have to seperate the words. I don't think there is any direct way of doing what you're looking for without separation of words either with `RichText`, `GestureDetector` etc.

Comment: Yeah will check

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Text("This Is the Question 1"),
          ),
```

If you want to make a specific part of your text clickable then use this code.

```
          RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              text: 'This Is the ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
              children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                    text: 'Question',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                    ),
                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                      ..onTap = () {
                        print("It's Working");
                        // Do Your CLickable Logic Here
                      }),
                TextSpan(
                  text: ' 1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Check Now. This what you're looking for

Comment: I also wrote the same thing in the question's comment section but the OP isn't looking for this way.

Comment: This is not the way I am looking for

Comment: It's wasn't working because it has no style.Try Now.

Comment: @OttomanCoder I told you this is not something the OP is looking for!

Comment: Can you tell what he's looking for??